# Connecting Geodesign and attributes of two layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, design, spatial-relationship

I'm kind of new in QGIS and I wonder if there is a function or a tool to connect Geodesign and attribute of two layers, for example:

I have a line vector layer named as (MT) with the attribute below

[image]

[image]

And a point layer named (HH) with the attribute below

[image]

So when I draw a point on the (MT) line layer the field "Route" in the point layer should take the info. of the field "Route Type" in the (MT) line layer as shown below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "Join Attributes by Location" under Vector-Data Management Tools? Wont update every time you create a point though

Comment: Try a default field value. Install the refFunctions plugin and write an expression using the `geomintersects` or `geomnearest` function.

Comment: The  refFunctions works great thank you very much